# How can I activate a service after the desktop on raspberry pi (not immediately with boot)?

Tags: service, raspberry-pi3, autostart

I want to launch an executable script python automatically. How can I activate a service after the desktop on raspberry pi?

I want to launch an executable script python automatically. How can I activate a service after the desktop on raspberry pi?
When I launched the service at the boot, it's failes (need some library python).
I'll try autostart, sudo nano /etc/rc.local and service.

Nothing works.
So, the answer i think is to launch the script automatically after boot.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the script run in crontab, for it to run after a few seconds upon reboot. For example:

```
@reboot sleep 20 && /usr/bin/python my_script.py
```

Hope it helps!